# How to determine the yield / send / return values for any generator in python

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

Looking at the following: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Generator

I'm not sure how one would know what the yield/send/return value is for any given generator?

The `yield` value seems easy, as I assume one can just do `type(next(<generator>))`, but the others aren't so clear.

## example

For example, I'm not sure how one would typehint the following :

```py
# note - this is not meant to be useful...

import pathlib

def list_of_paths(paths) -> list[pathlib.Path]:
    return list(paths)

path_list = list_of_paths(paths = pathlib.Path('.').glob('*'))
```

How to know what to use in `Generator`?

```py
from typing import Generator
import pathlib

def list_of_paths(paths : Generator[pathlib.Path, ? , ? ]) -> list[pathlib.Path]:
    return list(paths)

path_list = list_of_paths(paths = pathlib.Path('.').glob('*'))
```

## edit

Continuing with the example of `pathlib.Path.glob`, the documentation is https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob

It's note clear here what the `send / return` types for this generator are.

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, I rarely ever use `Generator`. If you're type hinting and only care about the yield value (which is usually the case I find), just use `Iterator`. A generator is an iterator with extra stuff, so that's a valid hint. In this case you'd just use:

```
def list_of_paths(paths: Iterator[pathlib.Path]) -> list[pathlib.Path]:
    return list(paths)
```

To attempt to literally answer the question though, you'd need to dig into the source/documentation of the function and try to reason about what the types are. For `glob` specifically, if I load this into Pycharm:

```
import pathlib

p = pathlib.Path()
x = p.glob()
```

and if I mouse-over `x` and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> (by default), I get a little dialog that says `Generator[Path, None, None]`, which is Pycharm's inference.

Also, if I mouse-over `glob` and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>, I get taken to the source of `glob`, which is:

```
def glob(self, pattern):
    sys.audit("pathlib.Path.glob", self, pattern)
    if not pattern:
        raise ValueError("Unacceptable pattern: {!r}".format(pattern))
    drv, root, pattern_parts = self._flavour.parse_parts((pattern,))
    if drv or root:
        raise NotImplementedError("Non-relative patterns are unsupported")
    selector = _make_selector(tuple(pattern_parts), self._flavour)
    for p in selector.select_from(self):
        yield p
```

And from that, I can tell that it doesn't receive or `return` any values, so both of those must be `None`. So basically, if you want to fill in those fields, you'll need to either rely on documentation, a good static analysis tool like Pycharm, or check the source and infer it yourself.

Comment: thanks - it's useful info and (i think) relevant, but I am curious how one would / should go about finding out this information - unless this information should *not* be used when type hinting generators like what I've given as an example (some documentation supporting that would be useful though)

Answer (score 2):

The `generator` runtime type implements two related but separate concept:

- [generator coroutines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/) which repeatedly wait for messages and reply, and
- [simple generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) which provide a stream of values.

The reason why `generator` implements both is that a "simple generator" can just be implemented as a "generator coroutine" that replies with its values to empty messages.

As a result, `typing.Generator` also represents both concepts:

- `Generator[YieldType, SendType, ReturnType]` encodes "generator coroutines", and
- `Generator[YieldType, None, None]` encodes "simple generators".

So just because one encounters a `generator` or `typing.Generator` does not mean there are send and return types.

---

It is generally viable to assume that a "generator" means a "simple generator" unless explicitly indicated otherwise. The [Python glossary: generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) only describes the "simple generator" kind, and [Python glossary: coroutine](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-coroutine) refers to `async` functions – a bare "generator coroutine" is very rare in Python usage.

Given a description like that of [`pathlib.Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) which says "*yield*ing all matching files" and never mentions send or return values, it is safe to assume one deals with a "simple generator".

When in doubt, use [MyPy's `reveal_type`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/common_issues.html#reveal-type) to show the static type of an expression:

```sh
$ mypy -c "from pathlib import Path; reveal_type(Path('.').glob('x'))"
<string>:1: note: Revealed type is 'typing.Generator[pathlib.Path*, None, None]'
```